# Do not show autocomplete popup when cycling through options in ST3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Sublime has built-in auto complete. It works fine, but I would really like to know how to disable autocomplete popup but still be able to cycle through completions using Tab with word under cursor changing right away?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this with a combination of two settings, shown here with the default values:

```
    // When enabled, pressing tab will insert the best matching completion.
    // When disabled, tab will only trigger snippets or insert a tab.
    // Shift+tab can be used to insert an explicit tab when tab_completion is
    // enabled.
    "tab_completion": true,

    // Enable auto complete to be triggered automatically when typing.
    "auto_complete": true,
```

`auto_complete` controls whether the autocomplete popup appears automatically or not, so setting that preference to `false` in your user preferences will stop the popup from appearing unless you manually cause it to appear with the appropriate key binding (the default is <kbd>Alt+/</kbd> on Linux and <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> everywhere else).

Regardless of the value of that setting, if `tab_completion` is set to `true` (which it is by default) then that command will try to insert the best matching completion at current cursor location, and as long as you don't move the cursor or take any other actions you can continue to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle between all of the available completions.

Comment: But I don't really want to see the popup at all and cycle through completions using the same key (Tab and shift+tab). Instead, it just inserts the best completion and in order to cycle through all of the options, I have to use this awful popup, which is sometimes very hard to close in Vintage mode, as it requires two ESC presses.

Comment: Are you saying that in Vintage even when you set the value of `auto_complete` to `false` as the answer suggests, it still appears? I

Comment: Yes, it appears when I press Tab.

Comment: If changing the setting of `auto_complete` to `false` from the default of `true` doesn't change the behaviour, then I would guess that something has remapped the key so that it no longer respects the value of the setting. The default binding for that key disables itself when that setting is `false`.